# AchartEngine timeseries double value to date

Tags: date, double, converters, achartengine

I can add the date/time value for the X axis to TimeSeries and if I use getPadding(), it returns a double so how can I convert this double to date again ?

Example returned double value: 1.40669949E12 (Also I tried to convert from string but not worked.)

now I want to convert this value to formatted date, Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are getting needs to be rounded to a `long` using `Math.round()` and then using this `long` you can build a `Date` that you can format any way you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
String format = "h:mma"; // for example
Double d = 1.40669949E12;
String formattedStr = new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(new Date(Math.round(d)));
```